# Cannot refer to referenced project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview - Version 16.9.0 Preview 1.0 ; .NET version `5.0.100` ; Windows 10 x64 version 2004 ; ASP.NET Core Blazor webassembly.

I have 3 projects:

- `a133.Server` (reference `a133.Shared`)
- `a133.Client` (reference `a133.Shared`)
- `a133.Shared`

This is inside project `a33.Shared`
[image]

This is inside project `a33.Client`
[image]

Even, I use full path

[image]

[image]

```
3>------ Build started: Project: a133.Server, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>CSC : error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Users\donhuvy\source\repos\a133\Client\bin\Debug\net5.0\ref\a133.Client.dll' could not be found
3>Done building project "a133.Server.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 3 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tried remove reference, then re-adding. I also tried rebuild projects. Reference is still error, how to fix it?

Comment: This fact maybe cause confusing: I moved `a133.Server.Models` from project `a133.Server` to project `a133.Client` . Namespace in client is `a133.Client` as default folders created by Visual Studio 2019 Blazor webassembly project template.

Comment: Your (entity/domain) Models should be in the Server project and the DTOs in the Shared. Client usually uses the DTOs as Models or it can define its own. Client and Server should _not_ reference each other.

Comment: It seems that you also referenced Client in the Server, isn't it ?